# how to call the function knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

```
var ViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.Check = function(){
        alert('ok');
    }
};    

$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());      
});
```

** how to call a function `Check()` in normal script from knockout**

Comment: Where do you want to call it from? It's just a normal Javascript function so you call it like any other Javascript function.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep a reference to your view model:

```
var myVM = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(myVM);
```

Now you can call the function:

```
myVM.Check();
```

But if you want to be able to use it outside the doc ready, you'll need to return it from there and assign it to a variable, or use a global variable.

So you could do something like this:

```
var myVM = new ViewModel();

$(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(myVM);
});

//...
myVM.Check();
```

If you wanted to use this function as an event handler (for example, to handle a click) you'd do something like this (in HTML):

```
<a data-bind="click: Check">Click me to check!</a>
```

For other events, you'd use the [event](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html) binding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind it to a function do this:

js:

```
var ViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.Check = function(){
        return "Ok";
    }
};    

$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());      
});|
```

markup

```
<span data-bind="text:Check()" />
```

See fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/P4bP7/